# Counting in Scheme without recursion?

Tags: list, count, scheme

So, I have a homework assignment that is asking me to make a function that counts the number of elements in a list *without* using recursion. (Which seems crazy to me, since Scheme is all about recursion from what I've learned so far, but that's a different discussion.) We're also not allowed to use the built-in `length` function.

I'm assuming this involves `map` somehow, but beyond that, I'm stuck, and everything I've googled for help offers a recursive solution (or uses !set, which the class hasn't taught us about and which I'm *assuming* is not the answer they're looking for).

Comment: Can you use `apply`? More specifically, could you combine `map` and `apply` in some useful way?

Comment: ''apply'' hasn't been covered in the course, so I'm assuming that's not what they're asking us to do. We've pretty much only covered ``define``, ``let``, ``lambda``, ``append``, ``car``, ``cdr``, and ``cons``.

Comment: It's easy using a `fold`, but that involves recursion under the hood... Scheme doesn't even *have* iteration in the normal sense, so you kind of have to use recursion one way or another to do it.

Comment: Do they consider (+ 1 (f (cdr l))) to be recursion but (f (+ 1 a) (cdr l)) to be iteration?

Comment: You could use `for-each` (which is like `map`, but used for side-effects) together with `set!`, or you could even use `map` with `set!`; or you could use a `do` loop. But it sounds like none of these methods is available to you.

Comment: I asked the teacher, and apparently, we're supposed to use recursive functions that were defined earlier in the assignment, and those don't count as recursion for purposes of this question. So it was just poorly worded instructions.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Every looping construct in Scheme is just syntax sugar for recursive functions so if you run the same line twice you are doing it with recursion. `do`, `map`, `for-each`, even continuations that end up as loops are recursive functions.

Comment: "use recursive functions that were defined earlier in the assignment" so which functions are those?

Comment: In instructions, "write a function that doesn't use recursion" usually means that the function itself should not recurse, not that it shouldn't call other functions that might be recursive.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a rather fussy definition of recursion: a function is recursive iff it calls its own name, either directly or indirectly, then you can write things which are not 'recursive' in this very limited sense, by, really, noting that functions that don't have names can't be recursive (again: in this limited sense).

So you can start with this slightly odd function:

```
(λ (f)
  (λ (l)
    (if (null? l)
        0
        (+ 1 ((f f) (cdr l))))))
```

This is a function which takes another function, `f` as an argument and returns a function which takes a list as an argument and which:

- if the list is empty will correctly compute its length;
- if the list is not empty, then if `(f f)` is a function which will correctly compute the length of the `cdr` of the list, this function will compute the length of the whole list, by adding one to it.

So, wait: this function, if given another function which, when called with itself as an argument, will return a function which will compute the length of the rest of a list, will compute the length of a list.  That means that this function *itself* is a candidate for this `f` function: *when called with itself as an argument* it should return a function which computes the length of a list.  So, OK, we can wrap it up a bit to make this proposed length-computing function:

```
((λ (g)
   (g g))
 (λ (f)
   (λ (l)
     (if (null? l)
         0
         (+ 1 ((f f) (cdr l)))))))
```

Should be a function which computes the length of a list.  And we can try it:

```
> (((λ (g)
      (g g))
    (λ (f)
      (λ (l)
        (if (null? l)
            0
            (+ 1 ((f f) (cdr l)))))))
   '(1 2 3))
3
```

Well, it does seem to compute the length of the list.  So we can, finally, give this thing a name to make it easier to call:

```
(define list-length
  ((λ (g)
     (g g))
   (λ (f)
     (λ (l)
       (if (null? l)
           0
           (+ 1 ((f f) (cdr l))))))))
```

And now

```
> (list-length '())
0
> (list-length '(a b c d))
4
```

OK.

So, conventionally, this is done by giving the thing that applies a function to itself a name: it's the U combinator:

```
(define U
  (λ (f) (f f)))
```

And then we can rewrite `list-length` in terms of `U`:

```
(define list-length
  (U (λ (f)
       (λ (l)
         (if (null? l)
             0
             (+ 1 ((U f) (cdr l))))))))
```

And the question is: is `list-length` recursive?  Well, maybe?

Comment: `(U (λ (f) (...(U f)...) )) => {f = (λ (f) (...(U f)...))} in (...(U f)...)` and thus that inner `(U f)` <s>is</s> *will create* the same expression as that `(U (λ (f) (...(U f)...) ))`, when called in `((U f) (cdr l))`. /side note

Comment: ... *will create it* when the symbol `f` is dereferenced (variable `f`'s value is found and used in place of the variable `f`).